# RPi 3B+ Ethernet crashes TP-Link Archer C9

Tags: ethernet, pi-3b+

When I use the ethernet connection on my RPi 3B+ my Archer C9 (TP-Link router) works fine for 20-30 minutes then crashes and reboots indefinitely until the RPi ethernet is disconnected. The RPi and router function normally via WiFi connection. Also there are 2 other pre-existing ethernet connections that are stable. I have tried adjusting the iptv / LAN options without success. I am at work now but have access to the log from yesterdays issues..

Things that are / were running on the pi: 
Watching 720p live stream w/ OMXplayer
VNC - no active connections 
Nginx server
Deluge
Pulseaudio (not currently broadcasting)
Python web scraping scripts that run hourly on 15th minute
Omxremote

```
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <3> 288753 Config importing failed
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288009 Failed to read WAN_ON
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288003 Led rule name is WAN_ON
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288001 Receive data length = 132
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <6> 288051 Start to run WAN1_ON
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288004 WAN1_ON is found
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288003 Led rule name is WAN1_ON
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288001 Receive data length = 132
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <6> 288051 Start to run WAN0_OFF
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288004 WAN0_OFF is found
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288003 Led rule name is WAN0_OFF
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288001 Receive data length = 132
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <6> 288051 Start to run LAN_ON
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288004 LAN_ON is found
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288003 Led rule name is LAN_ON
2019-05-09 15:55:55 led-controller[942]: <7> 288001 Receive data length = 132
2019-05-09 15:55:19 nat[8558]: <6> 211021 IPSEC ALG enabled
2019-05-09 15:55:19 nat[8558]: <6> 211021 L2TP ALG enabled
2019-05-09 15:55:19 nat[8558]: <6> 211021 PPTP ALG enabled
2019-05-09 15:55:19 nat[8558]: <6> 211021 SIP ALG enabled
2019-05-09 15:55:19 nat[8558]: <6> 211021 RTSP ALG enabled
2019-05-09 15:55:19 nat[8558]: <6> 211021 H323 ALG enabled
2019-05-09 15:55:19 nat[8558]: <6> 211021 TFTP ALG enabled
2019-05-09 15:55:19 nat[8558]: <6> 211021 FTP ALG enabled
2019-05-09 15:55:19 nat[8558]: <6> 211024 DMZ disabled
2019-05-09 15:55:18 nat[8558]: <5> 211055 Port trigger created succeeded[trigger-port:8112 trigger-protocol:all ex-port:8112-8112 ex-protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:18 nat[8558]: <7> 211002 Port triggering:trigger match 8112 and trigger relate 8112
2019-05-09 15:55:18 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:800 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:80 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:17 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:80 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:80 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:17 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:8081 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:8081 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:16 qos[11117]: <6> 259504 Service start
2019-05-09 15:55:16 qos[11117]: <6> 259503 Function disabled
2019-05-09 15:55:16 qos[11117]: <6> 259505 Service stop
2019-05-09 15:55:16 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:8112 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:8112 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:16 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:1080 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:1080 protocol:udp]
2019-05-09 15:55:15 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:22 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:22 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:15 upnp[10748]: <6> 217504 Service start
2019-05-09 15:55:14 upnp[10748]: <6> 217505 Service stop
2019-05-09 15:55:14 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:23 ip:192.168.2.181 in-port:22 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:13 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:8082 ip:192.168.2.181 in-port:8082 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:13 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:8114 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:7878 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:12 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:9117 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:9117 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:12 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:8113 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:5050 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:11 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:5959 ip:192.168.2.181 in-port:5959 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:10 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:8080 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:8080 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:10 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:4212 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:4212 protocol:all]
2019-05-09 15:55:09 nat[8558]: <5> 211054 Virtual server created succeeded[ex-port:8000 ip:192.168.2.126 in-port:8000 protocol:all]
```

Comment: What are you doing on the Pi?

Comment: I was watching a 720p live stream. I also have nginx and deluge on it. I have been playing with pulseaudio recently but nothing was broadcasting to the network

Comment: You need to edit all relevant information into the question.

Comment: Ok added some info. I am thinking to try tonight to see if pulseaudio is causing the issue.

Comment: What is Archer C9? If it crashes, for what reason ever, it's not a problem of a Raspberry Pi. But that's a condition for questions on this site.

Comment: Archer C9 is a router made by TP-Link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like there was some program - I'm guessing it's pulseaudio but still cant pinpoint it(?) - that was making IPv6 requests and crashing the router. I tried everything to block IPv6 requests system-wide but the only thing that worked was turning activating IPv6 on my router.. not ideal but it works I suppose.